# How to fill Cells of GridbagLayout with the controls in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I need to design a swing GUI which has a JFrame with a Menu on top and another main panel having three more panels in center and a separate panel in the bottom of the panel. The required design of the UI is as below[image]
But when I run my swing application I get the output like this (all the panels are packed in the center of the window)

[image]

Below is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrontEndView {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel,subPanelUp,subPanelDown,panelLeft,panelRight,panelCenter,panelDown;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JList logViewList;
    private JPanel panel1;

    public FrontEndView(){
        this.prepareGUI();
    }

    public void prepareGUI(){
        mainFrame=new JFrame("GUI");
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
        int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
        mainFrame.setSize(xSize,ySize);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(true);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        mainPanel=new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        GridBagConstraints gridbagConstMain = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gridbagConstSub = new GridBagConstraints();

        subPanelUp=new JPanel();
        subPanelUp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        subPanelUp.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        panelLeft=new JPanel();
        panelLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Message Defs"));
        gridbagConstSub.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridbagConstSub.weightx = 0.5;
        gridbagConstSub.gridx = 0;
        gridbagConstSub.gridy = 0;
        subPanelUp.add(panelLeft, gridbagConstSub);

        panelCenter=new JPanel();
        panelCenter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Main Workspace"));
        gridbagConstSub.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridbagConstSub.weightx = 0.5;
        gridbagConstSub.gridx = 1;
        gridbagConstSub.gridy = 0;
        subPanelUp.add(panelCenter, gridbagConstSub);

        panelRight=new JPanel();
        panelRight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Script Viewer"));
        gridbagConstSub.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridbagConstSub.weightx = 0.5;
        gridbagConstSub.gridx = 2;
        gridbagConstSub.gridy = 0;
        subPanelUp.add(panelRight, gridbagConstSub);

        mainPanel.add(subPanelUp,gridbagConstMain);

        subPanelDown=new JPanel();
        subPanelDown.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelDown=new JPanel();
        panelDown.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Log View"));
        logViewList= new JList();
        panelDown.add(logViewList);
        gridbagConstSub.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        //gridbagConst.ipady=20;
        //gridbagConst.weightx = 0.0;
        gridbagConstSub.gridwidth = 5;
        gridbagConstSub.gridx = 0;
        gridbagConstSub.gridy = 0;
        subPanelDown.add(panelDown,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        mainPanel.add(subPanelDown, gridbagConstSub);

        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(mainPanel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        mainFrame.add(scrollPane);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FrontEndView  frontEnd = new FrontEndView();
    }
}
```

I want to fill the GridBagLayout's cells with the relevant panel/control it holds as shown in the design and also each panel should have its controls filled inside (I need to add a JList inside the panelDown whose size should be the size of the panelDown JPanel).Simply I don't need any extra space visible in my JFrame. Please guide me on what is missing in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you can use nested panels with different layout managers to solve the problem.

The default layout of a frame is a BorderLayout.

So you could create a panel and add it to the PAGE_END so it displays the entire width at the bottom.

Then you can create another panel that uses a GridLayout. You can then add 3 child panels to this panel and each panel can use its own layout. Then you add this panel to the CENTER of the frame. As the frame size changes the extra spaces will be allocated to the CENTER so the panels will dynamically grow.

Edit:

Too many panels for me to take the time to understand what is happening

I was suggesting a structure like this:

```
frame (which by default uses a BorderLayout)
--- CENTER
    panel using GrigBagLayout
        childPanel1
        childPanel2
        childPanel3
---- PAGE_END
    JScrollPane containing the JList
```

When you create the JList the basic code would be:

```
JList list = new JList(...);
list.setVisibleRowCount(5); 
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
```

There is no need to create a panel just to add the list to another panel. The point of setting the visible row count is to give the JList a fixed height. Scrollbars will then appear in the scroll pane as needed.

Now that the PAGE_END has a fixed height component all the reset of the space will go to the component that you add to the CENTER of the frame.

> all the panels are packed in the center of the window)

The panels are displayed at their preferred sizes when you use the GridBagLayout. If the total size of all the panels is less than the size of the scrollpane then they will be in the center. If you want the panels to fill the space available, then I believe you need to use the weightx/y constraints. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) which describes all the constraints.

That is why I suggested a GridLayout instead. It will make all the panels the same size and will fill the viewport of the scroll pane without playing with constraints.

```
mainFrame.add(menubar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

That is not how you add a menubar to the frame.

You should be using:

```
mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

You were told this in your last question. Why did you not listen to the advice??? Why should we take the time to help when you don't pay attention to what is suggested.

Comment: @Sherihan I can't possible read the code in a comment. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (in your original question) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I did edit the code above to check only whether the panelDown aligns as required but still having the same issue.can you check it out?

Comment: @Sherihan `can you check it out?` - no because you haven't posted a `SSCCE`. I can't compile that code. And the code related to the menus is not relevant so it should NOT be included in the SSCCE. The SSCCE should be a small as possible.

Comment: I have posted SSCCE. can you please check it out?

Comment: @Sherihan, That is NOT a SSCCE!!! I specifically stated the code related to the menus was not relevant. We don't want to spend time reading through unnecessary code to understand what you are doing. We want YOU to spend the time isolating the code directly related to the problem. See edit for more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your instructions I changed my design in a way all of the outer panels are used with Border Layout and the inner most ones with more controls were used with Grid, GridBag and FlowLayouts based on the requirement. In that way the entire design could be done nicely.

Also if a particular panel within a cell of a layout needs to be expanded, I used the setPreferredSize(new Dimension(int,int)) whenever required.